# Peer to peer collaborative text editing

Tags: javascript, web, synchronization

I am building something very much like Google Docs where two people can edit a document simultaneously. I've read quite a bit about [Differential Synchronization](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/), written by a Google engineer. He provides a working solution. However, in my case it's going to be peer to peer between max 2 clients - and his solution does not work for peer to peer (with no server in between) the way I see it. And since the article is over 5 years old I was hoping there would be something new in this area.

So basically I'm looking for resources (articles, videos etc) that proposes a solution for peer to peer collaborative text editing between two clients.

Comment: What will be the editing interface? Local app, web browser, etc.

Comment: @Drewness Website, so I'm going to be using Websockets (it's not real peer to peer, but the server can't be a part of the solution).

Comment: You could have one of the peers acting as the sever. Also, check out the HTML5 [specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) on websockets.

Comment: @Drewness Yes, indeed! But if I understood it correctly only one message can be sent at a time (or the system will pull back the changes). That means just one can be typing at a time.

Comment: No, it's async. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm) is another good document on websockets.

Comment: @Drewness I was referring to the Differential Synchronization system on the link I posted :)

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for [share.js](http://sharejs.org) which offers a decent updated version of [Operational Transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). You should be able to work it out over [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org) to handle a bidirectional peer to peer pipe in javascript.

N.B.: just for the fun, I wrote some time ago [yace](https://github.com/guyzmo/yace) based on share.js, it's still using a central point, but I really think you can use bricks of share.js and make a peer-to-peer version.

Edit / N.B.2: I linked a project that was not relevant to the question, but the friend doing that project made one that is more relevant: [scratchpad](https://github.com/tOkeshu/scratchpad)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [CryptPad](https://github.com/xwiki-labs/cryptpad) (Free/Libre and Open Source). Encryption carried out in your web browser protects the data from the server, the cloud and the NSA. This project uses the CKEditor Visual Editor and the ChainPad realtime engine. The secret key is stored in the URL fragment identifier which is never sent to the server but is available to JavaScript so by sharing the URL, you give authorization to others who want to participate.

[image: CryptPad screenshot]

Also, you should look at the other Collaborative Editing algorithm, [Operational Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation).